# Difference between "below of=" and "below=of" in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I was trying to place a node relative to another node with the following code:

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  facility/.style={rectangle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,
                   minimum width=20mm,align=center,
                   text width=20mm,font=\footnotesize},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[facility] (sup)                 {Supplier Facility};
  \node[facility] (cust) [right of=sup] {Customer Facility};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is shown below.
Unfortunately the two nodes are overlapping, which is not what was desired.

[image]

I realized that my mistake was that I needed to replace `right of=sup` with `right=of sup`.

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  facility/.style={rectangle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,
                   minimum width=20mm,align=center,
                   text width=20mm,font=\footnotesize},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[facility] (sup)                 {Supplier Facility};
  \node[facility] (cust) [right=of sup] {Customer Facility};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code above gives the desired output:

[image]

#### Question

1. Why is `right of=sup` different from `right=of sup`?
2. If `right of=` is wrong, why doesn't it give a compile error or warning?
3. Is it possible to make `right of=` give a compile error or warning?
   This seems like a particularly easy mistake to make.

Comment: have you seen [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386) it seems relevant

Comment: Title says "below of=/below =of" but example use "right of=/right =of".